# IOS Safari fullscreen video(iphone) with html/js

Tags: video, safari, mobile-safari, fullscreen

I see that safari has partial support for the webkitfullscreen api, iphones are excluded.

screenshot of browser suppor fullscreen api

[image: 1]

I wonder how you can play a video in fullscreen since it is not supported since a youtube.com running in safari can provide a fullscreen view of the video. If i request the fullscreen option it is not available but are their workarounds or other smart tricks to receive this result. I feel like i want to basicly tell the user, use a browser with normal functionality and leave safari for what it is...

Chrome and firefox are working but safari i cannot find a solution to play the video in fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

iOS safari does not support the standard HTML5 fullscreen as you have seen.

There are workarounds which effectively stretch the view element so it is 100% of the available window space.

Videojs is an open source player that does this and may be a good example to use or to look at - the flag they use is 'preferFullWindow' : https://videojs.com/guides/options/#preferfullwindow